# this error occurs when I want to launch google sign in flutter authentication

Tags: flutter

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] 
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(
channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null
)
```

Comment: Please include steps you have done so far

Comment: When I remove this if the error goes away
but when I recover the error comes back and the application starts more
noted that
i did all this step if
*flutter pub outdated

*flutter pub upgrade firebase_messaging

*flutter clean

*flutter pub get
 my steps change

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question and add a bit more details about the error. For example, does it come from a installed plugin? Which plugin is that? Does it happen in a specific line? Then copy-paste the related code too.

Comment: After adding this

await Firebase.initializeApp();

Answer (score 0):

Some common issues you can check for

1. If you are using firebase to integrate google sign in. Make sure tou enabled sign in with google
2. Download the json/plist from firebase and add it to the project
3. If you are checking in ios add the reversed client id in info.plist.
4. Make sure you added your certificate sha keys in firebase before you download the json/plist
5. If you are using cli you can omit most of these steps.

**Edit**

There are 2 sets of sha keys. When you upload an app bundle google signs an apk. This key needs to be updated in firebase.

You have to copy keys from app sign in key section. The release jks's keys is named here as upload key certificate.. use the app sign in key's sha 1 and sha256 in firebase and download the json. Add it to the app and reupload. This should work as expected

[image: preview]

Comment: these what i did

Comment: Are you checking app from Google Play? Internal testing or production..

Comment: Internal testing ,if all the tests are good I put it in production